# ActionScript, Flash, and Optimization

Tags: flash, optimization, actionscript, adobe, cs3

I have a few specific questions that the general webpages dealing with optimization just didn't answer for me me(So please don't point me to them :)).

So here goes:

1. Is checking the "Use runtime bitmap caching" check box on a movieclip the same as setting the cachasbitmap property in code?(I suspect that it is, but just to be sure, I'm asking...)
2. Does bitmap caching affect objects that are not on stage?
3. I know bitmap caching is supposed to have an adverse affect on a movieclip with it's timeline playing, but what about a movieclip that has stopped, but has embedded movieclips inside that are still playing?
4. On an older computer of mine, using bitmap caching for an object that is always on stage has decreased performance. But on a newer computer, it has made performance better. Does anyone know why this is exactly?
5. Is there a difference between a graphic object on stage full of vectors, and any object that has an actual bitmap image inside?(I noticed that the "Use runtime bitmap caching" check box becomes disabled for graphic objects.)

Furthermore, this is flash CS3 on XP systems. Thanks for any help on the matter.

I checked the adobe forum, but **all** those topics have 0 replies, so I came here.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer some of the questions:

Answer to 3) Yes, this is the same case because the Flash Player still needs to regenerate bitmap versions of the changing frames.

Answer to 4) It's very hard to tell, there are many reasons why this can happen. However, there's a very plausible explanation: I guess Flash defines a size for the bitmap cache depending on how much memory the computer has available. If the computer has less memory, the cache can become too small and, as a consequence, Flash will need to constantly refresh the cached bitmaps.

Answer to 5) Can't really understand what you mean here... Perhaps if you clarify...

Comment: Thanks. For number 3, lets say you have a face bobbing left and right that is a movieclip. Then, within that face are the eyes which is another movieclip. The face has stopped its bobbing, but the eyes are still blinking. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Stack Overflow messed with the numbers, I was replying to questions 3, 4 and 5 (not 1, 2 and 3)... Read my answer again :)

Comment: Oh okay :). Well to elaborate on 5 then, you know when you create an object in flash, how you have a choice of movieclip, button, and graphic? I mean the difference between a graphic object with vector shapes in it, and any object be it movieclip or graphic that just has a bitmap inside.(The library type seen when you import an image).

Comment: Furthermore, I've proved that for question 2, it does in fact influence objects both on and off the stage. On the older computer, stopping all inner clips on objects off stage with bitmap caching enabled for them improved performance significantly.